# Error on installing Curl in Red Hat

Tags: redhat, curl

Got this error when i installed curl in my  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server

```
 ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ERR_remove_thread_state'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [curl] Error 1
 make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/src/curl-7.26.0/src'
 make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src/curl-7.26.0/src'
 make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any idea on how to get this fixed?

Comment: What's wrong with `yum install curl`?

Comment: I am not familiar with yum so i have to google it, so i would know how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

The linker cannot find the library containing ERR_remove_thread_state, which I believe is supplied by openssl. Does your command line (or makefile) point to the openssl libraries (assuming the appropriate version is installed in the first place)?

As the comment suggests, it might be easier to use yum to install pre-compiled software and to resolve any dependencies. There might be a case for doing that (using yum to identify and resolve dependencies) even if you then wish to build it from source yourself.

Comment: I run yum command through SSH, it told me to run rhn_register, i followed the step by step instruction but it wasn't successful at all. It asked for username and password which i don't know. I entered the root access but it says invalid credentials. Here is the output i got from the terminal [link] http://pastebin.com/szR670qQ [/link]

Comment: You need to run rhn_register in order to associate your system with the account that will (or should) have been set up by whoever bought your copy of RHEL 5: your employer, perhaps? You can use either a username and password or a special key, but you will need to discover these from whoever looks after the RHN account for your company. If you bought the licence yourself, go back and read all the email that came with it!

Comment: I am trying to contact the person who set up the server before. I wish to here a response from him.